# CentOS 7.8 duplicate package

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

One of my CentOS 7.8 machine I see duplicate package installed. how to clean-up older version of these rpms.

```
# rpm -qa |grep NetworkManager-1
NetworkManager-1.18.4-3.el7.x86_64
NetworkManager-1.18.0-5.el7_7.2.x86_64
```

**Yum Check command output**

```
 # yum check
    Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror, rhnplugin
    1:NetworkManager-1.18.4-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-1.18.0-5.el7_7.2.x86_64
    1:NetworkManager-libnm-1.18.4-3.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-libnm-1.18.0-5.el7_7.2.x86_64
    acl-2.2.51-15.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with acl-2.2.51-14.el7.x86_64
    avahi-libs-0.6.31-20.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with avahi-libs-0.6.31-19.el7.x86_64
    bash-4.2.46-34.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with bash-4.2.46-33.el7.x86_64
    32:bind-export-libs-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-export-libs-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.x86_64
    32:bind-libs-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-libs-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.x86_64
    32:bind-libs-lite-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-libs-lite-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.x86_64
    32:bind-license-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.3.noarch is a duplicate with 32:bind-license-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.noarch
    32:bind-utils-9.11.4-16.P2.el7_8.3.x86_64 is a duplicate with 32:bind-utils-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.x86_64
    binutils-2.27-43.base.el7_8.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with binutils-2.27-41.base.el7_7.2.x86_64
    centos-release-7-8.2003.0.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64
    conntrack-tools-1.4.4-7.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with conntrack-tools-1.4.4-5.el7_7.2.x86_64
    2:container-selinux-2.119.1-1.c57a6f9.el7.noarch is a duplicate with 2:container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch
    cryptsetup-libs-2.0.3-6.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with cryptsetup-libs-2.0.3-5.el7.x86_64
    1:cups-libs-1.6.3-43.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-40.el7.x86_64
    curl-7.29.0-57.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with curl-7.29.0-54.el7_7.2.x86_64
    7:device-mapper-1.02.164-7.el7_8.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-1.02.158-2.el7_7.2.x86_64
    7:device-mapper-event-1.02.164-7.el7_8.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.158-2.el7_7.2.x86_64
    7:device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.164-7.el7_8.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.158-2.el7_7.2.x86_64
    7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.164-7.el7_8.2.x86_64 is a duplicate with 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.158-2.el7_7.2.x86_64
    device-mapper-persistent-data-0.8.5-2.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with device-mapper-persistent-data-0.8.5-1.el7.x86_64
    12:dhclient-4.2.5-79.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhclient-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.x86_64
    12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-79.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-common-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.x86_64
    12:dhcp-libs-4.2.5-79.el7.centos.x86_64 is a duplicate with 12:dhcp-libs-4.2.5-77.el7.centos.x86_64
    dracut-033-568.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with dracut-033-564.el7.x86_64
    dracut-network-033-568.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with dracut-network-033-564.el7.x86_64
    e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-17.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with e2fsprogs-libs-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64
    elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.176-4.el7.noarch is a duplicate with elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.176-2.el7.noarch
    elfutils-libelf-0.176-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with elfutils-libelf-0.176-2.el7.x86_64
    elfutils-libs-0.176-4.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with elfutils-libs-0.176-2.el7.x86_64
    expat-2.1.0-11.el7.x86_64 is a duplicate with expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a result of `yum update` being interrupted hard.

Run `yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only` to fix the issue.

Comment: I am getting this message `No unfinished transactions left.`

Comment: Looks like you had a catastrophic failure and your transaction history got wiped. I could have fixed that for you privately. Google me.

Comment: `package-cleanup --cleandupes` might work for you.